# Correctness of Performing Logistic Regression in reverse to a Linear Regression Model (swapping independent and dependent variables)

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, independence

Linear regression is used as follows:

```
lm(Continuous1 ~ Factor_3Level * Factor_2Level, data = Data1)
```

What are the problems following this up with this:

```
glm(Factor_2Level ~ Continuous1 + Factor_3Level, data = Data1, family = "binomial")
```

The variable names describe the data types. `Factor_3Level` and `Factor_2Level` are independent. The results from `lm()` are that both factors are significant, the interaction term is not significant ($p=.23$), and the R-squared is $0.34$.

`Continous1` was measured under test conditions, where each combination of the levels of the two factors (six possibilities) was tested 25 times. (These two factors were physically altered for the test.)  The assumptions of linear regression are satisfied. `Continous1` does not "exist" without the two factors having values.  It is assumed there are multiple unknown environmental factors which also affect `Continuous1` (which are difficult to identify and/or measure).

I think independence is violated by using logistic regression this way. As `Factor_2Level` is tied to the conditions of the original test. The regression will probably be significant, but I don't think the r-squared will be accurate. Is that correct? Is there a different reason a test like this should not be done in reverse? What is the name of the related principal?  In reverse, the independent variables can't be causing the dependent variable, rather the model predicts what state the dependent variable is in.

Insofar as a concrete example is required, consider the following. The behavior of animal K1 in a wildlife park is being measured, such as pacing/hour (times around the perimeter). The manipulated variables are the presence of a neighboring animal, V2, in a certain extended area, which can be selected for with a gate (and waiting briefly), and the selection can be done on a rainy day, sunny day, or cloudy day.  If the park officials don't know whether V2 is present in the neighboring area, can the pacing rate of K1, given that it's sunny (the most significant factors from the earlier multiple regression test study) give them a good idea?

**This question is about the validity of manipulating or selecting for an environmental variable, and then turning around and trying to predict that variable.  This question is not about the example.**

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? The question isn't clear.

Comment: @Kyle -- I just want to confirm something: how many levels do the variables `factor_2Level` and `factor_3Level` have respectively?

Comment: @abalter factor_2Level has 2 levels; factor_3Level has 3 levels.

Comment: @StatsStudent Factor_3Level X Factor_2Level is six groups, and each group has 25 samples. Given this, and the lack of interaction, why do you think they are correlated?

Comment: @StatsStudent  I added a concrete example. ("Why are you trying to do this?)

Comment: @Kyle, if factor_3Level has 3 levels, then you can't use the binomial family of `glm` logistic regression only makes sense for two levels. However, you can use multinomial regression (which can be thought of as a type of logistic regression). I had thought that `glm` did this, but I think you need the `nnet::multinomial` function.

Comment: @abalter  That's a typo, I will fix.  The dependent variable is Factor_2Level.  Although I would think that glm would do ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: I would have thought so too, but the only examples I can find used `nnet`. So, just to be clear, you are controlling `factor_3Level` and `continuous`, and then measuring `factor_2_level`?

Comment: THIS QUESTION DOES NOT LACK DETAILS OR CLARITY.   I have accepted the accepted the best answer given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the problems following this up with this

If there are any problems, I think they are scientific.  In the first model, what you are modelling is the outcome, let's call it $y$, given the two factors $x$ and $z$.  The data generating process would be

1. Draw jointly $x$ and $z$.  You claim they are independent so this is the same as drawing $x$ then $z$ or vice versa.
2. Use both $x$ and $z$ to draw $y$.  The model you've written down is a model for $y \vert x,z$.

However the second model would be a model for $z \vert y,z$ which is at odds with the first model's data generating process.  In the first model you say that $z$ can be used to draw $y$ where as in the second $y$ is used to draw $z$.  Statistically, not a problem because the three variables have some joint distribution and factoring that distribution anyway you like is mathematically allowed, but scientifically it would give me some pause.

Can you speak more about what these variables represent?

Comment: I added a concrete example to the description - the last paragraph.  ("Can you speak more about what these variables represent?)

Comment: I agree, but I'm looking for something more concrete - ("but scientifically it would give me some pause.")

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Cross Validated!

Here are some thoughts:

1. Because correlation is not the same as causation, without knowing *a priori* that there is a single, known causal direction, there is no reason why cannot consider any variable as the response variable. Only further experimentation can tell you if there is a distinct causal direction.
2. p = 0.23 does **NOT** mean that two variables "do not interact." It only means that you don't have enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis of zero slope in your particular model, with your particular data. Something to **drill in your head over and over** is that a non-significant p-value does not prove no effect. Your hypothesis test is only constructed to either **reject or fail to reject** the null hypothesis of no effect.
3. It is perfectly reasonable to run your model in two directions. Such situations occur all of the time. Does the presence of a chemical in the blood cause a condition or result from it? Or, do both result from some other cause? There are, of course, things that cannot be response variables, such as the genotype of a subject.

### Additional tips:

1. Look for additional variables that you might need to include in your model.
2. Do a lot of exploratory analysis. Make sure you study your data visually.
3. Do all of the requisite regression diagnostics to make sure your data and model conform to the assumptions of the type of regression you are performing.

I hope this helps.

### Continued based on additional information from OP

1. If `factor_3Level` and `factor_2Level` are independent, it could still make sense to include one as a predictor and one as an outcome if one acts as an effect modifier of `continuous`.

However...

2. If I understand correctly, you experimentally adjusted `factor_2Level` and `factor_3Level`, and then measured `continuous`. In this case, perhaps I was wrong to say that you could consider any variable as the outcome. I was thinking in terms of observational data.
3. I think what you have is a straightforward two-way (2x3) ANOVA model `continuous ~ factor_3Level*factor_2Level`. Of course, that is roughly equivalent to linear regression, but you would want to handle multiple comparisons differently (e.g. Tukey, Bonferroni).
4. Regarding the assumptions, after you run `lm` you need to look at the residuals, qq plot, etc. Regression diagnostics.

Is that more helpful than before?

### More based on information from comments

Consider the problem:

> The gate is behind a screen and you don't know if it is open or not. You observe the animal pacing and want to predict if the gate is open or closed.

Yes, you could *definitely* perform logistic regression of gate (open/closed) on weather, pacing `gate ~ pacing + weather`. This amounts to asking a specific statistical question: Can I categorize the gate state by observing weather and pacing.

That being said, from the little I know of Bayesian statistics, that may be a better framework. But logistic regression would be a good start nevertheless.

Alternatively, you could consider other classification methods from the machine learning repertoire such as Bayes nets or discriminant analysis. I can't be much help with that.

Comment: Apparently the following wasn't clear, so I updated the post with it: "(These two factors were physically altered for the test.)"  I assumed that was clear.

Comment: I added a concrete example to the description (last paragraph).

Comment: Based on your concrete example, it sounds like the dependent variable is pacing. That can't change either which gates you open, or the weather. 

How are you measuring pacing? Is it the act of taking steps or changing direction, or is it a true rate such as feet/hour. The former is a count variable (think Poisson regression), while the latter is a continuous rate. You should probably measure more variables: instance of pacing, time of instance, distance of instance, time between pacing events.

Comment: "Pacing" is one round around the perimeter, in a varying fashion.  The animal doesn't continually pace - it varies from 0 to 6 times per hour.  If the gate is open, the other animal will move to that that extended area 100% of the time.  Yes, the pacing rate doesn't open the gate, but is it valid to use the pacing rate as an indicator that the gate is open (other animal is present)?

Comment: Oh I see--interesting question. The gate is behind a screen and you don't know if it is open or not. You observe the animal pacing, and want to predict if the gate is open. Yes, I think you could definitely perform logistic regression of gate (open/closed) on weather, pacing.

Comment: I'm assuming the animal doesn't pace _exactly_ from the set of integers {1,2,3,4,5,6} times per hour, but that you are assigning those integers as something representative of approximately how many times the animal has circumnavigated the area. Also, it sounds like one pace may take a different amount of time than another. If that is an established method in the literature, then stick to it. If not, then you might want to consider another way to measure pacing based on a count or ordinal variable. It doesn't seem like a continuous variable to me.

Comment: This is an example.  The question isn't about study design. It's about the validity of manipulating or selecting for an environmental variable, and then turning around predicting the manipulated or selected-for variable.

Comment: Yes, you are asking a specific statistical question of whether you can categorize the gate state by observing weather and pacing. That being said, from the little I know of Bayesian statistics, that may be a better framework. But logistic regression would be a good start nevertheless.

Comment: If you think I have answered your question (yes you can do that), please accept.

Comment: I'm going to wait 2-3 days to see if someone sees a problem.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of issues here

1. are you even certain you are *doing* a logistic regression? Assuming that is R, you’ve not specified the link function and i don’t know your data types
2. if you are doing correlation, do correlation. If you are doing glm, do glm. Each method has accepted practice of follow up comparisons (regression = regression contrasts, glm = Tukey, Scheffe, etc etc). Mixing and matching is a quagmire.
3. I suspect, but cannot prove, you’ve messed with your actual Alpha rate.

Comment: Running glm(.. family="binomial" as given) in R shows that the residual deviance is a 25% reduction of the null deviance, and Continuous1 is significant at .01. Factor_3Level is not significant, and it was not significant in the original regression. The term is included as an example.  (The variable names are descriptive of their type).

Comment: This is where I am with the general validity question.  ("I suspect, but cannot prove, you’ve messed with your actual Alpha rate.")

Comment: @HEITZ -- 1) you do not need to always specify the link function. If you use `family=binomial`, R defaults to `link=logit`. 2) He did not say he is "doing correlation." He was merely talking about variables being correlated. This is a useful thing to be concerned with in regression analysis. 3) There is no need for multiple comparisons here unless he goes with the ANOVA option I suggested.